# hierarchical linear model?

Tags: r, multilevel-analysis, random-effects-model

Yes, another question asking if my hierarchical general linear model is written correctly, and if the question I am asking is being tested.

Basically, we have 63 subjects answering 48 (`Recog`) questions. Each question is split into group one or group two (`Format`). I want to ask if the effect of `Format` still holds when the effect of a third variable, `Time`, is included.

I am doing my analysis in R. I want the variability within `Subject` to be taken into account, so I include it as a random effect. My model looks like this:

```
glmer(Recog ~ Time + Format + (1|Subject),family=binomial)
```

Does this appropriately answer my question? If `Format` is still significant, can I say that the effect of `Format` on `Recog` is still significant when controlling for `Time`, or is that too far? Maybe significant when including `Time`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, another MLM question indeed! My favorite.

Your model looks right to me. If `Format` is still significant in this model, you can say that the effect of `Format` on `Recog` is still significant when controlling for `Time`.

The only additional thing I would suggest doing is including random slopes. Right now, your random effects structure only contains `1`, the random intercept. Since `Format` is measured at Level 1, the effect of `Format` might be different for each subject. This variation could be modeled by specifying the random effects structure as: (1 + Format|Subject)

You could save the model with that random effects structure as one model and then do a nested model comparison using the likelihood ratio test to see if the random slope is significant. [See my post here on how to do that.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/276555/130869)

If `Time` is also a Level 1 variable, you could consider using that as a random effect, as well. This would tell you that the influence of `Time` on `Recog` varies by person.